# RF device connection issue

Tags: pcb, rf

I have a surface acoustic wave based separator device built on piezoelectric (PZT) substrate and this is mounted on a PCB for the external connection as you can see from the picture.

When I was working with this device in Norway, I used wire bonding to connect the PCB and the metal strips on the PZT substrate.

As I moved to new place I don't have this wire bonding machine available here.

So I was thinking can any of you brilliant people please give your insight about how to do the connection without the wire bonding?

I have some ideas like connecting with conducting tape or conductive epoxy glue pen but I am not sure.

This device works with 13MHz frequency.

So I am not sure if the conducting tape can withstand this frequency.

I can't use soldering because the most common tin solder will remove my thin gold layer from the PZT device.

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: I'd have my doubts about conductive epoxy.  Less because of the frequency.  Rather, conductive epoxy is a far cry from a piece of wire as far as resistance goes.  Might also be a problem because of vibration.

Comment: Maybe you could look into spring contacts.

Comment: DO you think it will work if I connect one piece of wire on both sides with the conducting tape?

Comment: [Pogo pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin)

Comment: I think anything with tape or epoxy is more likely to damage things than to be useful.